# Using linux commands with "symbol-named" files

Tags: linux

How can I use various linux commands such as `cat`, `ls`, `touch`, `more`, `less` ... with file named as symbols as `-` `/` `--` and so on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A slash `/` cannot *ever* appear in the file's name, because it is the path separator.

**When a file name starts with a dash,** programs normally try to interpret it as an option, and there are two ways to avoid this:

- **Use the special `--` option** that means "everything after this will be only names, not options". For example, if you have files named `-rf` and `--hello--`, you can use:

  ```
  rm -- -rf --hello--
  ```
- Or, more simply, **make the names *not* start with a dash**, by giving full paths to them. For example, you can specify that they're in `.` (the current directory), ending up with:

  ```
  rm ./-rf ./--hello--
  ```

  Or you can use a full path:

  ```
  rm /home/Krishath/-rf /home/Krishath/--hello--
  ```

The other case is when there are special symbols in the middle of a name (`-` is not special; `$` would be special).

- First **try "escaping" them with a `\`**. For example, if you have a file named `wei"rd$na'me`, use:

  ```
  cat we\"ird\$na\'me
  ```

  This works with everything, including spaces, and is the easiest way when you only have one or two symbols to deal with.
- Another method is to put quotes around it. Unfortunately quoting in command-line shells is a bit confusing – sometimes both `'name'` and `"name"` work, sometimes only one of them.

  (For example, the special symbols `|` or `<` can be double-quoted but `$` or `` ` `` cannot. On the other hand, single quotes will work with everything *except* when the file name itself contains a single quote.)

  However, if the file name simply has spaces, then quotes will certainly be easier:

  ```
  mv "Some long file name.txt" ~/trash
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To delimit the option list use `--` i.e. type the following command:

`ls -l -- *.txt`

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-move-file-starting-with-a-dash/